# Localization at prime ideals of the infinite direct product of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, localization

> How to find the localization at a prime ideal of infinite direct product of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, i.e. $ \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z \times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \cdots$ ?

I know there is a question related to this but that question only prove the localization of this ring is a field, but did not specifically tell what the ring is after localization.

Some hints and explanations would be really helpful!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be the ring given by
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty F_2$$
and let $K = R_P$, for some prime ideal $P$ of $R$.

Let $S = R\setminus P$.

Noting that $r^2 = r$, for all $r\in R$, it follows that one of $r,\;1-r$ is in $P$, and the other is in $S$.

Suppose $x$ is a nonunit of $K$.

Write $x = r/s$, where $r \in R$, and $s \in S$.

Since $x$ is a nonunit, we must have $r \notin S$, hence $1-r \in S$.

Then $x = {\large{\frac{r}{s}}} = {\large{\frac{0}{1-r}}}$, hence $x=0$.

Thus, zero is the only nonunit of $K$, so $K$ is a field.

Let $x$ in $K$.

Writing $x =  {\large{\frac{r}{s}}}$, where $r\in R$, and $s \in S$, we get
$$x^2 
=
\left({\small{\frac{r}{s}}}\right)^2
=
{\small{\frac{r^2}{s^2}}}
=
{\small{\frac{r}{s}}}
=
x
$$
but then, since $K$ is a field, $x^2=x$ implies $x=0$ or $x=1$.

Thus, $K$ is isomorphic to $F_2$.

Comment: I don't understand why since x is a non-unit, we must have r is not in S... and I also don't understand why x=0/(1-r) followed..

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: If $r \in S$, then ${\large{\frac{s}{r}}}\in K$, but then, by the definitions of multiplicaton and equaltity in $S^{-1}R$, we get
$$\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)\left(\frac{s}{r}\right)=\frac{rs}{rs}=\frac{1}{1}$$
so $x$ is a unit of $K$.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: Suppose $x$ is a non-unit of $K$. Let $x = {\large{\frac{r}{s}}}$, where $r \in R$, and $s \in S$. Since $x$ is a non-unit of $K$, we have $r \notin S$. But that implies $1-r\in S$, hence ${\large{\frac{0}{1-r}}}\in K$. But $r^2 = r$, hence, by definition of equality in $S^{-1}R$, we get ${\large{\frac{r}{s}}}={\large{\frac{0}{1-r}}}$, so $x=0$.

Comment: I am sorry that I always get confused. Why $r^{2} = r$ implies $\frac{r}{s} = \frac{0}{1-r}$?

Comment: By definition of equality in $S^{-1}R$, we have
$$\frac{r_1}{s_1}=\frac{r_2}{s_2}$$
if and only if r1s2 = r2s1 (i.e., the cross-multiplication _works_). Hence, if $1-r \in S$, we get
$$\frac{r}{s} = \frac{0}{1-r}$$
since $(r)(1-r)=(0)(s)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is a Boolean ring, meaning every element is idempotent, then $A_P$ is a local ring where every element is idempotent. Local rings have no non-trivial idempotents, so $A_P$ is the field of two elements.